# Opening an Exe From ASP page on client PC

Tags: asp.net, web

I have a simple ASP application that opens and run an Exe in the current PC,

```
Partial Class _Default
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

      Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
           Shell("C:\\\Project1.exe")
      End Sub
End Class
```

This works in my computer, but when i put it in the server, and run the script from a client pc, it opens the application in the server not in the client pc.

Why is this happening, and can i bypass it?

Thank you.

Comment: Think about this for a moment; what if there were some way to run an arbitrary .exe on a client machine from a web page? Would that be a good thing for browsers to allow? How many people do you think in the world would add a command like `cmd.exe /c "rmdir c:\*"` to their web page?

Comment: Well, you can put a message before it execute it ...

Answer (score 0):

The webserver cannot open applications on the client; it can only return a file, with the intention of the browser of opening it...

Comment: Is there any way to open another EXE from the web in the client PC?
ANY other way, java applet jquery ... ??

Comment: In short, no. After all, what if the remote user is not using a pc, but a phone, or reader or...

Comment: Is there anyway then to open an HTML file located in the client pc then?

Comment: The web server does not know what is located on the client PC, so no. It can *send* the client HTML, but it can make no assumption about the client.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can execute an .exe from a browser is if you have access to the computer in question. I have used this previously in a CyberCafe/Kiosk application. I got the idea from observing Google Desktop.

Basically, you need to have a lightweight HTTP server in the users computer (I chose [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/) because it's Http server object can be hosted in any application)

The principle is to have the installed application (your web server) execute the .exe in response to an Http request.